# Say "Anchorlink" that Target Element got dynamic margin-top

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, margin

I have a little "big" Problem and don't know how to resolve.

If i have an link with an anchor that jumps to an element with margin-top, the margin is "ignored" like in the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/T38uk/

If i have an div with margin-top="0" and there will dynamically added some margin-top, the anchor jumps to the "old" position like in the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Gd/

Is it possible to tell the anchor that there is a dynamically changed margin on the target element?

Here are the single Code snippets:

HTML

```
<a href="#testanchor" class="link">Testanchor</a>
<div id="zwischenelement"></div>
<div id="testanchor">Hier muss der Anker hinspringen</div>​
```

CSS

```
body {
   height: 8000px;        
}

.link {
   display: block;
}

#zwischenelement {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: grey;    
}

#testanchor {
   margin-top: 40px;  
   background-color: red;
   padding:15px;   
}​
```

JS (the "scrollAnimate" jQuery Plugin is included)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#testanchor').scrollAnimate({
    startScroll: 0,
    endScroll: 100,
    cssProperty: 'margin-top',
    before: 0,
    after: 40
});

});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to replace the normal link click action with a jQuery function which scrolls to the element's current position, PLUS the number of pixels you expect it to be moved down:

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).scrollTop($('#testanchor').position().top+40); 
    // 40 pixels is specific to this case
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eG2Gd/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to get the anchor to point to the top of the margin for the div because it is linking to the div and the margin is only spacing above your div.  Either you are going to need to do something like Blazemonger suggested, or create a div around the div you want to link to and link to that.

For example:

```
<a href="#testAnchorHolder" class="link">Testanchor</a>
<div id="zwischenelement"></div>
<div id="testAnchorHolder">
    <div id="testanchor">Hier muss der Anker hinspringen</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#testAnchorHolder {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#testanchor { 
    background-color: red;
    padding:15px;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FchLX/

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but thats not my problem ;)
I don't want to go to the top of the margin ... i want to go directly to the div but if some margin is added via javascript the anchor only knows the "old position" and do not jump to the top of the div.

Comment: Ahh, in that case you are going to have to use javascript to set the scroll position because the div is being moved after the page is rendered.  As it is, the browser is putting you at the correct position, then you are moving the div.